# How to optimize group with lot of meshes?

Tags: three.js

I load OBJ with ObjLoader2. ObjLoader2 converts OBJ to group with a large number of meshes. As my OBJ is really huge, performance is really bad. Is there possibility to increase performance but to keep info about all parts of OBJ because it is needed to keep possibility to select every mesh?